# What is the correct sequence of negatives for this use case?

Tags: grammaticality, negation

Which of the following sentences is most grammatical for US English, or are all of them ungrammatical and should be written differently?

> I will not allow anyone to do something to him or her.
>
> I will allow no one to do something to him or her.
>
> I will allow anyone to do something to neither him nor her.

The intent is to state that the speaker is going to prevent anyone and everyone from taking an action as regards to "him" and "her".

Comment: They're all awkward, at least, for irrelevant reasons, as usual. Why use both _anyone_ and _something_? It sounds like a contradiction. Why use _him or her_ instead of _them_? And negation is not just a matter of sticking a negative word in here or there; there are scopes, constructions, and polarity to consider.

Comment: (1) and (2) would be just about acceptable if you replace _something_ with _anything_.

Comment: @KateBunting Which of 1 and 2 is more grammatical and fitting to the intent? And yes, "do something" is just for asking on ESE. In the actual text it will be along the lines of "screw", "smite", "smash", "paint", "drive" or whatever. The specific action is irrelevant.

Comment: So, you seem to be using “to do something“ and “him or her” as placeholders and you are only interested in the structure around these. (This wasn’t obvious at all until you explained it to us.) If I fill in the placeholders I can make much better sense of the different sentences: I get:   **1.** “I will not allow anyone to hurt Lenny.”  **2.** “I will allow no one to hurt Lenny.”  and both are grammatical and possible in ordinary usage. I’d expect to come across **1.** much more often (especially with “won’t”). I still can’t derive any sensible meaning from **3.**

Comment: Perhaps with **3.** (your third sentence) you are trying to use something like: “I will allow anyone to hurt **not** Lenny.”? If so it is certainly grammatically incorrect to try to negate the sentence in this position.